# Сброс статуса кнопки после выполнения запроса

Tags: javascript

```
$('.update').live('click', function() {
    $(this).button('loading');
    $('#listInserts tr').remove();
    updatelist();

    $(this).button('reset');
    $(this).button('complete');

});
```

Вопрос в том как сделать так, чтобы `$(this).button('reset');` и `$(this).button('complete');` выполнились после того, как обработается функция `updatelist();`, а не сразу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

заведите колбек:

```
function updatelist(callback)
{
    ...
    // update list
    ...   
    callback();
}
```

и передавайте его в функцию:

```
$('.update').live('click', function() {
    $(this).button('loading');
    $('#listInserts tr').remove();
    var that = this; // это не самый лучший способ сохранения контекста
    updatelist(function(){ // <= callback
        $(that).button('reset');
        $(that).button('complete');
    });
});
```

если в `updatelist` вызываются асинхронные функции, то передавайте колбек в методы такие как `.success` или `.error`, которые могут быть у асинхронных функций